# ViewModel, Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток

Tags: c#, исключения, viewmodel

В общем есть публичный класс RootViewModel наследуемый интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged, с публичной коллекцией :

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> m_Logs;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Logs
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Logs;
        }
        set
        {
            m_Logs = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Logs));
        }
    }
```

Забинден в xaml к элементу ListView

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Logs, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1" FontSize="11"/>
```

Собственно, если обращаться к коллекции из синхронного метода, то все хорошо, как только запускаю в Task, сразу выскакивает ошибка "Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному....."
Дело в том, что хочу запустить сокет-сервер таким кодом:

```
    public async void RunServer()
    {
        // получаем адреса для запуска сокета
        IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);

        // создаем сокет
        Socket listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // связываем сокет с локальной точкой, по которой будем принимать данные
            listenSocket.Bind(ipPoint);
            
            // начинаем прослушивание
            listenSocket.Listen(10);
            App.ViewModel.Logs.Add("Сервер запущен. Ожидание подключений...");

            while (true)
            {
                Socket handler = listenSocket.Accept();
                // получаем сообщение
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                int bytes = 0; // количество полученных байтов
                byte[] data = new byte[256]; // буфер для получаемых данных
                do
                {
                    bytes = handler.Receive(data);
                    builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                }
                while (handler.Available > 0);

                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ": " + builder.ToString());

                // отправляем ответ
                string message = "ваше сообщение доставлено";
                data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
                handler.Send(data);
                // закрываем сокет
                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                handler.Close();
            }

        });

        try
        {

            
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Но в данном случае при обращении к коллекции "App.ViewModel.Logs.Add("Сервер запущен. Ожидание подключений..."); " Вылетает ошибка, если же запустить метод синхронно, то оператор while не дает запуститься основной программе и интерфейс не загружается.

Так же пробовал обращаться к коллекции через Dispatcher

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => App.ViewModel.Logs.Add("Сервер запущен. Ожидание подключений..."));
```

Ошибка не исчезает, что я делаю не так? ") Или может как то по другому сделать? ")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` из вашего предыдущего ответа использовать нельзя, так как вы можете просто повредить данные, если вызовете его повторно до того как предыдущий вызов завершится.

Я не знаю точно, почему так происходит, ведь вызов делегата фактически произойдет внутри UI потока, и можно считать его потокобезопасным, но `ObservableCollection` не так проста как кажется. Помимо добавления элемента в коллекцию, для этого элемента вызывается событие `CollectionChanged`, чтобы интерфейс мог отследить изменения и обновиться, и здесь кроются сюрпризы, типа вы закидываете одновременно 2 элемента в коллекцию, а собыития вызываются не в том порядке, в котором элементы были добавлены в коллекцию, и в результате получаются неверные данные в интерфейсе.

Чтобы обезопасить себя от подобных сюрпризов, нужно вызвать делегат с блокиованием текущего потока, пока добавление элемента в коллекцию не завершится полностью. Это не занимает много времени, поэтому можно просто подождать:

```csharp
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    App.ViewModel.Logs.Add(message);
});
```

Но данный способ не иделаен, представьте себе, у вас 3-4 коллекции, и вы их модифицируете в разных местах кода. И каждый вызов вам придется оборачивать в делегат, и закидывать в `Dispatcher`.

---

Есть способ лучше, использовать вот такой потокобезопасный вариант коллекции:

**AsyncObservableCollection.cs**

```csharp
public class AsyncObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private readonly SynchronizationContext _context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    private void ExecuteOnSyncContext(Action action)
    {
        if (_context.Equals(SynchronizationContext.Current))
            action();
        else
            _context.Send(_ => action(), null);
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item) => ExecuteOnSyncContext(() => base.InsertItem(index, item));
    protected override void RemoveItem(int index) => ExecuteOnSyncContext(() => base.RemoveItem(index));
    protected override void SetItem(int index, T item) => ExecuteOnSyncContext(() => base.SetItem(index, item));
    protected override void MoveItem(int oldIndex, int newIndex) => ExecuteOnSyncContext(() => base.MoveItem(oldIndex, newIndex));
    protected override void ClearItems() => ExecuteOnSyncContext(() => base.ClearItems());
}
```

*Потокобезопасность проверена, гонял ее на тестах одновременно в 50 потоках с непрерывными модификациями, данные уцелели. Знаю, название грубое, так как здесь асинхронности как таковой нет, но зато коллекцию можно использовать в асинхронном коде и не задумываться о ручной синхронизации потоков при ее модификации.*

Класс просто наследует `ObservableCollection`, и переопределяет в ней вирутальные методы сверяя контекст синхронизации. Класс кросс-платфроменный, то есть будет работать и в Linux, и в Xamarin, но для WPF в Windows под капотом там тоже где-то зашит `Dispatcher.Invoke()`. В коде это `_context.Send()`.

Чтобы добиться желаемого результата, экземпляр данной коллекции обязательно надо создавать в основном UI потоке, так как при создании он захватывает текущий [`SynchronizationContext`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext?view=netframework-4.8), и в последствии использует его для перенаправления вызовов для модицикации коллекции.

Код написан таким образом, что если вы создадите эту коллекцию не в UI потоке, без контекста синхронизации, вы получите исключение `NullReferenceException` в строке `if (_context.Equals(SynchronizationContext.Current))` при попытке ее модификации. Обработку ошибок я не добавлял сюда специально, чтобы не ухудшать производительность класса, и чтобы ошибки использования было видно сразу.

---

Использование `AsyncObservableCollection` предельно простое

```csharp
private AsyncObservableCollection<string> m_Logs;
public AsyncObservableCollection<string> Logs
{
    get
    {
        return m_Logs;
    }
    set
    {
        m_Logs = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Logs));
    }
}
```

```csharp
Logs = new AsyncObservableCollection<string>();
```

И далее, просто из любого потока, без вызова диспетчера, напрямую.

```csharp
App.ViewModel.Logs.Add(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась следующим путем, для удобства использовал статический метод:

```
class Logs
{
    public static void Add(string message)
    {
        App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate ()
        {
            App.ViewModel.Logs.Add(message);
        });
    }
}
```

Таким образом диспетчер помещает операцию в связанный с ней поток. Следовательно, элемент всегда будет добавлен в поток пользовательского интерфейса.