# Как передать вызов события из одного объекта в другой?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть два объекта типа **DeviceManagerService** и типа **MainWindowViewModel**. Как дать понять объекту типа **MainWindowViewModel**, что событие произошло в **DeviceManagerService**.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModel
{
    #region Fields
    private string _title = "V-Voice";
    private ObservableCollection<Participant> _participants;
    private readonly DeviceManagerService _deviceManagerService;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public string Title
    {
        get => _title;
        set => Set(ref _title, value);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Participant> Participants
    {
        get => _participants;
        set => Set(ref _participants, value, "Participants");
    }

    public ICommand CloseApp => new CloseWindowCommand();
    #endregion

    public MainWindowViewModel(DeviceManagerService deviceManagerService)
    {
        _deviceManagerService = deviceManagerService;
        _participants = new ObservableCollection<Participant>(_deviceManagerService.Participants);
    }
}


public class DeviceManagerService : IDeviceManagerService
{
    public List<Participant> Participants => new List<Participant>();
    public VotumDevicesManager VotumManager => new VotumDevicesManager();

    public DeviceManagerService()
    {
        VotumManager.ButtonClicked += VotumManager_ButtonClicked;
    }

    private void VotumManager_ButtonClicked(object sender, ButtonClickEventArgs e)
    {
        AddParticipant(e);
    }

    public bool EnsureParticipant(int remoteNumber)
    {
        var prt = Participants.FirstOrDefault(prtRemote => prtRemote.Remote.NumberRemote.Equals(remoteNumber));
        return prt != null;
    }

    public void AddParticipant(ButtonClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (EnsureParticipant(e.RemoteId))
        {
            Participants.Add(
                new Participant
                {
                    FirstName = "Иван",
                    LastName = "Иванов",
                    Patronymic = "Иванович",
                    Remote = new Remote { IdKit = e.ReceiverId, NumberRemote = e.RemoteId, RSSI = e.RSSI, StatusMicrophone = StatusMicrophone.NotRecord },
                    Request = new Request { RequestEndTime = DateTime.Now }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: если в DeviceManagerService  произошло событие, то и добавьте событие в него (`public event ВашеСобытие`) и пусть VM на него подписывается

Comment: @tym32167 Т.е. добавить событие в DeviceManagerService, которое даст слежение за выполнением другого события?

Comment: я не знаю, что вы имеете ввиду и в коде не разбираюсь вашем. Но вы пишете `событие произошло в DeviceManagerService` - я вам только предложил это ваше утверждение в коде прописать и клиентам класса `DeviceManagerService` дать возможность подписываться на событие, которое возникает в классе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот здесь ошибка

```
public List<Participant> Participants => new List<Participant>();
public VotumDevicesManager VotumManager => new VotumDevicesManager();
```

Должно быть

```
public List<Participant> Participants { get; } = new List<Participant>();
public VotumDevicesManager VotumManager { get; } = new VotumDevicesManager();
```

Думаю, сами разберетесь, в чем разница.

Есть 2 основных варианта.

Объявить событие.

```cs
public class DeviceManagerService : IDeviceManagerService
{
    // ...

    public event Action MyEvent;

    private void VotumManager_ButtonClicked(object sender, ButtonClickEventArgs e)
    {
        AddParticipant(e);
        MyEvent?.Invoke();
    }

    // ...
}

public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModel
{
    // ...

    private void MyMethod()
    {
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel(DeviceManagerService deviceManagerService)
    {
        // ...
        deviceManagerService.MyEvent += MyMethod;
    }
}
```

Либо использовать `ObservableCollection`

```cs
public class DeviceManagerService : IDeviceManagerService
{
    public ObservableCollection<Participant> Participants { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Participant>();
}

public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModel
{
    // ...

    public ObservableCollection<Participant> Participants => _deviceManagerService.Participants;
}
```

И просто подписать на нее интерфейс, только надо следить за многопоточкой в этом случае. Если изменение коллекции произойдет из стороннего потока, то можно словить исключение. Либо использовать обертку вокруг коллекции, [типа этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1158131/373567), которая будет синхронизировать доступ к коллекции в UI поток.

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось.