# Как передавать разные SelectedItem из двух listbox в единственный DataContext?

Tags: c#, wpf

у меня возникла проблема с взаимодействием с отображаемыми элементами listbox. У меня есть два листбокса, один из которых используется для отображения отфильтрованных элементов. Вот xaml:

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">                                                           
    <ListBox x:Name="MessageListBox" Grid.Row="1"                                        
             IsVisible="{Binding IsMessageListBoxVisible}"                               
             Items="{Binding ReceivedApplicationMessages}"                               
             SelectedItem="{Binding ReceivedApplicationMessages.SelectedItem}"           
             AutoScrollToSelectedItem="False">                                           
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>                                                         
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>                                                     
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top"/>                    
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>                                                    
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>                                                        
            <ListBox.Styles>                                                             
                <Style Selector="ListBoxItem">                                           
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Topic,                 
                Converter={StaticResource MessageToColorConverter}}"></Setter>           
                </Style>                                                                 
            </ListBox.Styles>                                                            
    </ListBox>                                                                           
                                                                                         
    <ListBox x:Name="SearchListBox" Grid.Row="1"                                         
             IsVisible="{Binding IsSearchListBoxVisible}"                                
             Items="{Binding SearchApplicationMessages}"                                 
             SelectedItem="{Binding SearchApplicationMessages.SelectedItem}"             
             AutoScrollToSelectedItem="False">                                           
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>                                                             
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>                                                         
                <VirtualizingStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top"/>                        
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>                                                        
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>                                                            
        <ListBox.Styles>                                                                 
            <Style Selector="ListBoxItem">                                               
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Topic,                     
                Converter={StaticResource MessageToColorConverter}}"></Setter>           
            </Style>                                                                     
        </ListBox.Styles>                                                                
    </ListBox>                                                                                                                                                                
</Grid>
```

Я вывожу элементы и обрабатываю клик, используя `SelectedItem`, который потом передается вот в это место:

```
<StackPanel Margin="10">                                                             
    <subscriptions:ReceivedApplicationMessageDetailsView                             
        DataContext="{ Binding ReceivedApplicationMessages.SelectedItem.Details }" />
```

И если с `ReceivedApplicationMessages` все работает, то с `SearchApplicationMessages`, нет. Пробовал написать так:

```
<StackPanel IsVisible="{Binding IsMessageListBoxVisible}"  >                                  
    <subscriptions:ReceivedApplicationMessageDetailsView                                      
        DataContext="{ Binding ReceivedApplicationMessages.SelectedItem.Details }" />         
</StackPanel>                                                                                 
                                                                                              
<StackPanel IsVisible="{Binding IsSearchListBoxVisible}">                                     
    <subscriptions:ReceivedApplicationMessageDetailsView                                      
        DataContext="{ Binding SearchApplicationMessages.SelectedItem.Details }" />           
</StackPanel>
```

Но возникла проблемa - `SearchApplicationMessages.SelectedItem` не срабатывает

Во вьюмодели у меня такие коллекции:

```
private ConcurrentViewModelCollection<ReceivedApplicationMessageViewModel> ReceivedApplicationMessages { get; } = new ();
private ConcurrentViewModelCollection<ReceivedApplicationMessageViewModel> SearchApplicationMessages { get; } = new();
```

где `ConcurrentViewModelCollection` - это

```
public sealed class ConcurrentViewModelCollection<TItem> : ConcurrentObservableCollection<TItem>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{                                                                                                                       
    TItem _selectedItem = default!;                                                                                     
    public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;                                                      
    public TItem SelectedItem                                                                                           
    {                                                                                                                   
        get => _selectedItem;                                                                                           
                                                                                                                        
        set                                                                                                             
        {                                                                                                               
            _selectedItem = value;                                                                                      
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke( this,                                                                              
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs( nameof( SelectedItem ) ));                                                
        }                                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                   
}
```

Comment: Быть может забыли `INotifyPropertyChanged` реализовать. Несмотря на то что, решение выглядит немного странным образом, в разметке ошибок я не вижу. Не надо пробел после `{` и перед `}` в разметке ставить.

Comment: Я дополнил свой вопрос @aepot

Comment: `public new event` - зачем new? уберите эту строчку совсем, проблема верятнее всего именно здесь. Где гарантия, что UI подпишется на ваш PropertyChanged, а не на такой же базового класса? Зачем вам вообще этот SelectedItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public new event` - не надо так делать, совсем не надо.

**Вариант 1**

Привяжитесь прямо к DP `{Binding SelectedItem.Details, ElementName=MessageListBox}`

**Вариант 2**

`<ListBox x:Name="MessageListBox" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ...`, убрать привязку `SelectedItem` вообще. И привязаться к коллекции через CollectionView `{Binding ReceivedApplicationMessages/Details}`

Comment: Мне кажется, я сделал все, что вы сказали, но проблема не решилась.  Я дописал коллекцию, реализовав INotifyPropertyChanged https://pastebin.com/axKmLueE
А Details передаю вот так:
`DataContext="{ Binding  SelectedItem.Details, ElementName=MessageListBox }" />`
`DataContext="{ Binding  SelectedItem.Details, ElementName=SearchListBox }" />`

Comment: @penancewarrior Вы сделали не то что я сказал. Если бы вы сделали то что я сказал, у вас бы не вообще было свойства SelectedItem в этой коллекции. ConcurrentObservableCollection - вообще неиизвестно, что такое, и зачем оно вам. Обратите внимание, что вы привязываетесь к свойству листбокса, а показываете свойство вообще в другом месте. Как так?

Comment: хорошо, я убрал SelectedItem, теперь просто использую ConcurrentObservableCollection из библиотеки Swordfish.NET.Collections. Коллекция мне нужна, т.к в ней есть RemoveRange, InsertRange. Передав в DataContext (`SelectedItem.Details, ElementName=MessageListBox`) я получаю Details, все хорошо. Но передав в DataContext (`SelectedItem.Details, ElementName=SearchListBox`), я получаю ровным счетом ничего. Это означает, что ConcurrentObservableCollection работает, как надо, просто показывает Details элементов только одного listbox

Comment: @penancewarrior при этом в лисбоксах все на месте? Ок, попробуйте второй способ.

Comment: кстати, может вам это что-то даст. Вот собственно Details, к которым я обращаюсь: 
https://pastebin.com/HtGnhjHi
@aepot

Comment: @penancewarrior нет, ничего не дало.

Comment: @penancewarrior Я посмотрел исходники этой коллекции, коллекция является потокобезопасной, но не подходит для UI WPF, кто вам ее посоветовал? Она не захватывает контекст синхронизации, следовательно вызов обработчиков событий из UI может произойти не из UI потока. И черт его знает как при этом может вести себя интерфейс. Конечно, если вы будете ее модифицировать только из UI потока, то проблема неактуальна, но тогда куча тормозящего оверхеда внутри этой коллекции вам не нужна. Гораздо проще взять обычную ObservableCollection и дописать пару методов расширения.

Comment: @penancewarrior какие количества и как часто вам надо добавлять и удалять из коллекции? И нужно ли с ней работать из сторонних потоков?

Comment: У меня есть коллекция в которую постоянно добавляются элементы. Раз в секунду она очищается и все ее данные отправляются в другую коллекцию, которая уже биндится на ui. Я надеюсь, вам будет понятен код https://pastebin.com/Av499v4E
Также я написал метод для поиска, который ищет по ключевому слову все совпадения, добавляет в коллекцию, которая также биндится на ui

Comment: @penancewarrior для 10000 элементов, даже поэлементные добавления и удаления должны нормально работать. Вы же не по 1000 добавляете. И зачем кстати вам на экране столько? Туда отсилы сотня влезет. Кстати, внтури ConcurrentObservableCollection лежит та же ObservableCollection, так что прироста производительности она вам не даст вообще, только тормоза. А для многопоточки есть получше решение, специально для UI https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1158131/373567, чтобы можно было без обращения к диспетчеру модифицировать эту коллекцию.

Comment: ой, я пробовал обычное поэлементное добавление, но возникают проблемы - listbox, как я понял, перерисовывается каждый раз и все подвисает. Все еще сильнее подвисало, когда я делал `Insert(0, Collection)`. Приложение - логгер, поэтому и нужны последние 10 тысяч событий. Получается, проблема в том, что я использую коллекцию, которая не подходит для ui?

Comment: @penancewarrior для этого используется виртуализация. `Insert(0, Collection)` нету у `ObservableCollection`, там есть только вставка 1 элемента. Да, оно конечно может притормаживать, но не подвисать. И смысл логгера, если текст валится с такой скоростью, что его невозможно успевать читать, вы успеете 100 строк в секунду прочитать? А вот коллекция добавить их сможет. Второй нюанс, добавлять надо в конец, а не в начало, меньше будет тормозить. И последнее, под такие специфические требования лучше написать свою коллекцию, на базе какой-нибудь `Queue<T>`.

Comment: @penancewarrior посмотрите исходники `ObservableCollection` на гитхабе, там есть лишнее в ней, но механика реализации INotifyCollectionChanged+INotifyPropertyChanged+IList/IEnumerable вам должна быть понятна. Я бы за вечер справился, как переадресовать вызов в UI поток - чуть выше ссылка, и будет красота без всяких Dispatcher.Invoke.

Comment: заменил кастомную коллекцию на `ObservableCollection`, немного дописал и все заработало. Если честно, и подумать не мог, что в этом может быть проблема. Спасибо!