# Поток не может получить доступ в ViewModel слое при обновления CanExecute команды

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, mvvm

**Простая задача:** Обновить возможность выполнения кнопки по событию.

Пишу такой элементарный код при помощи [MVVM Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/):

```
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _ = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    CanTest = !CanTest;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        });
    }


    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(TestCommand))]
    private bool _canTest;

    [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanTest))]
    public void Test()
    {

    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

Как видно, тут создается простой класс, который фоном крутит некую задачу, и раз в секунду обновляет состояние `bool` свойства, по которому идет обновление `CanExecute` команды.

Для наглядности, что этот код сгенерирует:

```
public bool CanTest
{
    get => _canTest;
    set
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<bool>.Default.Equals(_canTest, value))
        {
            OnCanTestChanging(value);
            OnCanTestChanging(default, value);
            OnPropertyChanging(global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel.__Internals.__KnownINotifyPropertyChangingArgs.CanTest);
            _canTest = value;
            OnCanTestChanged(value);
            OnCanTestChanged(default, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(global::CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel.__Internals.__KnownINotifyPropertyChangedArgs.CanTest);
            TestCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
}

public IRelayCommand TestCommand => testCommand ??= new RelayCommand(new Action(Test), () => CanTest);
```

То есть, самая элементарная реализация `INotifyPropertyChanged` и `ICommand`, которая знакома многим.

**Теперь суть вопроса:**
Этот код приводит к ошибке

> Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток.

Оно и понятно, мы таском выходим из UI потока, из-за чего мы не можем так просто работать с UI, но как вернуться обратно? У нас есть [типичные решения данной проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/418463/220553), в которых используется `Dispatcher`. Ок, допустим, только это `ViewModel`, отдельный класс, который ничего не знает про UI, мы можем написать костыльно такое

```
public MainViewModel(Dispatcher dispatcher)
{
    _ = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { CanTest = !CanTest; }));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    });
}
```

и это решит проблему, но только это нарушение MVVM и прочих правил. Используя `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` мы также избавимся от ошибки, но у нас перестанут обновляться данные, что тоже вроде логично. Собственно, как решить проблему?

А да, само изменение свойства к ошибки не приводит, приводит обновления `CanExecute` (вызов: [TestCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet/blob/main/src/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm/Input/RelayCommand.cs#L62) ), который генерирует `[NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(TestCommand))]`. Если убрать, обновления в реальном времени у кнопки не будет, но `bool` свойство значение менять начнет.

---

P.S. Бесконечный `await` цикл это для примера, в реальном проекте у меня есть сервис, который отслеживает изменения процесса (запущен или нет), и отсылает событие наружу, это все зарегистрировано в контейнере, из которого и запрашивает ViewModel, где она подписывается и обновляет свойство, получая ошибку.

```
public class ProcessWatcherService : IProcessWatcher, IDisposable
{
    private readonly HashSet<string> _monitoredProcesses = new();
    public event EventHandler<ProcessChangedEventArgs>? ProcessChanged;

    private readonly ManagementEventWatcher _startWatch;
    private readonly ManagementEventWatcher _stopWatch;

    private readonly ILogger<ProcessWatcherService> _logger;

    public ProcessWatcherService(ILogger<ProcessWatcherService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;

        _startWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"));
        _startWatch.EventArrived += (_, e) => ProcessChangedEvent(e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value, ProcessStatus.Started);
        _startWatch.Start();

        _stopWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace"));
        _stopWatch.EventArrived += (_, e) => ProcessChangedEvent(e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value, ProcessStatus.Stopped);
        _stopWatch.Start();
    }

    public bool Verify(string process)
    {
        var result = Process.GetProcesses()
            ?.Any(x => x.ProcessName.ToLower() == Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(process).ToLower()) == true;
        _logger.LogTrace("Verify process status {process} = {result}", process, result);
        return result;
    }

    public void StartWatch(string process)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Process {process} added to watch list", process);
        _monitoredProcesses.Add(process.ToLower());
    }

    public bool AddAndWatch(string process)
    {
        StartWatch(process);
        return Verify(process);
    }

    void ProcessChangedEvent(object name, ProcessStatus status)
    {
        if (name is string processName && _monitoredProcesses.Contains(processName.ToLower()))
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Process {process} change status: {status}", processName, status);
            ProcessChanged?.Invoke(this, new(processName, status));
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _startWatch.Stop();
        _stopWatch.Stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно пойти тем же путём, которым реализован например [`Progress<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Progress.cs), то есть использовать захват `SynchronizationContext`.

При этом логически про UI поток знать необязательно. Нужно просто придумать контракт типа "я буду дёргать свойства вьюмодели в том же контексте синхронизации, в котором был создан этот экземпляр вьюмодели". Кстати, само по себе использование контекста синхронизации - кроссплатформенное решение, что является неоспоримым плюсом на фоне использования диспетчера.

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    private readonly SynchronizationContext _context;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // захват контекста
        _context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    }
}
```

Здесь рождается ограничение: вьюмодель должна быть создана в UI потоке. Иначе ничего не получится. Ну а дальше просто:

```
_context.Send(_ => CanTest = !CanTest, null); // ну или _context.Post, если ждать не хочется
```

(проверить на `null` контекст только не забыть перед использованием)

И это всё счастье можно завернуть в красивую упаковку с кодогенераторами и добиться чего-то вроде:

```
[ObservableSynchronizedProperty]
private bool _canTest;
```

То есть лепить синхронизированные свойства точно так же красиво, как обычные. Здесь нет взаимодействия с View даже под капотом, а следовательно и MVVM в безопасности (хотя в том же WPF UI контекст всё прекрасно знает про диспетчера и нагло на его основе работает).

Comment: Да, отличное решение, спасибо! Один вопрос, который покоя не дает... Почему я выхожу из UI потока, при `ProcessChanged?.Invoke(this, new(processName, status));`? Вроде вызываю не асинхронные методы, а из UI вышел...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ это синхронный вызов делегата, никакого выхода здесь быть не может.

Comment: Ну, я не совсем про это, я про мой основной код, который после `P.S.`. Где там может быть выход? Простые синхронные вызовы, а ошибку получил, как, почему, не пойму...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ быть может `ManagementEventWatcher` вызывает свой обработчик `EventArrived` в каком-то своём потоке?

Comment: Тоже на него грешу, ибо других мест с моей стороны нет, разве что IoC контейнер, но вряд ли он из UI выходить будет. Только вот информации не нашел про то, что он в другой поток уходит. Ладно, пойду генерацию кода освою, сделаю атрибут попробую)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ выяснить просто `Debug.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)` - посмотреть это для UI потока, а затем для обработчика. Контейнер выходить не будет, он синхронно работает.

Comment: Ну да, Id потока в событии `ManagementEventWatcher` другой, когда сам сервис в UI (1). А безопасно кстати использовать `SynchronizationContext` внутри сервиса, чтоб все подписчики его события сразу были в UI, или чревато проблемами?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ контекст потокобезопасный, ему фиолетово, из какого потока ему `Send` или `Post` вызвали. А дальше уже детали реализации. Для оптимизации можете проверять `if (_context == SynchronizationContext.Current) { я в контексте } else { я в рабочем потоке }`. Тогда валидные вызовы из UI потока к свойству пройдут короткой дорогой, например если сам View к свойству обратится. Ну и осторожней с безусловным вызовом `Send`, если его дёрнуть из UI, поймаете дедлок.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1158131/373567 `ObservableCollection` на потокобезопасных стеройдах.